# How does Mockito handle overlapping matchers with multiple arguments in the thenReturn block

Tags: java, mockito

I've got a block of test code that is attempting to, in the generic case return two values on subsequent calls, but in specific cases only return the value associated with that case. The code looks something like:

```
when(mockObject.method(anyString())).thenReturn(string1, string2);
when(mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput1"))).thenReturn(string1);
when(mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput2"))).thenReturn(string2);
```

The expected behavior is that when calling `mockObject.method("foo")` and `mockObject.method("bar")`, `string1` and `string2` should be returned respectively, but the test is actually seeing two responses of `string2`. Is this a bug in `Mockito`? Or am I misunderstanding `Mockito` pattern matching.

My assumption was that the last pattern to match is what is returned, but when going through that process does `Mockito` treat each argument in the first `thenReturn` block separately? Is there any way to get around this behavior?

When I comment out the second two when calls, the mocks behave as expected, so I'm assuming there is something specific about the overlapping matcher behavior.

Edit: This is in `Mockito` version `1.9.5`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem today. It is caused by calls to the mock to set up stubbing actually consuming the stubbing already in place.

In this example, change the first line to

```
when(mock.call(anyString())).thenReturn("","",string1,string2)
```

This will give you two blank responses when you set up your other mock returns, leaving string1 as the first useful return value.

Try also the doReturn alternative which I think may not have these issues:

```
doReturn(string1,string2).when(mock).call(anyString());
```

This uses the stub differently during setup.

So I did some more research on this. Here's the function I was playing with, based on the OP's question:

```
    Function<String, String> function = mock(Function.class);
    when(function.apply(anyString())).thenReturn("A","B","C");
    when(function.apply("Jim")).thenReturn("Jim");
    when(function.apply("Bob")).thenReturn("Bob");

    assertThat(function.apply("Jim")).isEqualTo("Jim");
    assertThat(function.apply("Bob")).isEqualTo("Bob");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("A");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("B");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("C");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("C");
```

The above fails at `isEqualTo("A")` because the two calls to set up the mocks for `Jim` and `Bob` consume return values from the list provided to `anyString()`.

You might be tempted to reorder the `when` clauses, but that fails, because the `anyString()` supersedes the special cases, so that fails too.

The following version of the above DOES work as expected:

```
    when(function.apply(anyString())).thenReturn("A","B","C");

    doReturn("Jim")
        .when(function)
        .apply("Jim");
    doReturn("Bob")
        .when(function)
        .apply("Bob");

    assertThat(function.apply("Jim")).isEqualTo("Jim");
    assertThat(function.apply("Bob")).isEqualTo("Bob");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("A");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("B");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("C");
    assertThat(function.apply("")).isEqualTo("C");
```

This is because the `doReturn` technique, which is intended for modifying pre-existing mocks in flight, doesn't actually involve calling the method on the mock to set up the mocking.

You could use `doReturn` for all setup, rather than mixing between `when`...`thenReturn` and `doReturn`..`when`..`function()`. As it happens, that's a bit uglier:

```
    doReturn("A").doReturn("B").doReturn("C")
        .when(function)
        .apply(anyString());
```

There's no convenient `varargs` function to let you specify multiple returns in sequence. The above has been tested and does work, though.

Comment: I tried the doReturn method and *think* I saw the same issue. I had a slightly different format so I've got to re-check. Thanks for the tip though! Any ideas if this has been fixed in more recent versions of Mockito?

Answer (score 2):

One way to workaround this problem could be to use a **regular expression** to avoid overlapping as next:

```
when(mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput1"))).thenReturn(string1);
when(mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput2"))).thenReturn(string2);
// Match with any input string that doesn't contain expectedInput1 neither expectedInput2
when(mockObject.method(matches("((?!expectedInput1|expectedInput2).)*")))
    .thenReturn(string1, string2);
```

*Example:*

```
System.out.println("expectedInput1=" + mockObject.method("expectedInput1"));
System.out.println("expectedInput2=" + mockObject.method("expectedInput2"));
System.out.println("foo=" + mockObject.method("foo"));
System.out.println("bar=" + mockObject.method("bar"));
System.out.println("bar=" + mockObject.method("bar"));
```

*Output:*

```
expectedInput1=string1
expectedInput2=string2
foo=string1
bar=string2
bar=string2
```

---

Another way could be to implement your `ArgumentMatcher` still to avoid overlapping:

```
when(mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput1"))).thenReturn(string1);
when(mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput2"))).thenReturn(string2);
when(
    mockObject.method(
        argThat(
            new ArgumentMatcher<String>(){
                @Override
                public boolean matches(final Object argument) {
                    return !"expectedInput1".equals(argument) 
                        && !"expectedInput2".equals(argument);
                }
            }
        )
    )
).thenReturn(string1, string2);
```

---

Another way could be to implement your `Answer` with something like this:

```
when(mockObject.method(anyString())).thenAnswer(
    new Answer<String>() {
        Iterator<String> it = Arrays.asList(string1, string2).iterator();
        String result;
        @Override
        public String answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            String argument = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            switch (argument) {
                case "expectedInput1" :
                    return string1;
                case "expectedInput2" :
                    return string2;
                default:
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        result = it.next();
                    }
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say whether that's a bug or a feature... The thing is, when you call `mockObject.method(eq("expectedInput1"))` to perform the second stubbing, the first stubbing is already in place. So *this* call returns `string1`, which is then uselessly passed to `when`. Subsequent calls return `string2`, and that includes the call for the last stubbing and later calls during actual testing.

I can hardly see any elegant way around it, short of using a custom `Answer` like @Nicolas suggested, although it does seem like an overkill. You could, perhaps, use a custom matcher instead of `anyString()`, that would essentially say “any string *except* those two”. This way you won't have one matcher intersect with another.

P. S. Now that @Nicolas edited his answer, that regular expression looks like exactly what I meant. Except that you don't need to implement a custom matcher after all.