# Does Mockito support throwing Exceptions in then(Answer) statements that are followed by thenReturn statements?

Tags: mockito

I have a situation where it looks like a call to when().thenReturn() is raising an exception that was defined in a when().then() statement.

This test passes:

```
@Test()
public void myTest() {
    List<String> list = mock(List.class);

    when(list.contains(any(String.class))).thenReturn(false);
    when(list.contains("A")).thenReturn(true);

    when(list.get(any(Integer.class))).then(new Answer(){
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return invocation.getArguments()[0].toString();
        }
    });
    when(list.get(0)).thenReturn("A");

    assertTrue(list.contains("A"));
    assertFalse(list.contains("B"));
    assertEquals("A", list.get(0));
    assertEquals("1", list.get(1));
}
```

This test throws a MyException (with message '0 is outside the array bounds') on the last line:

```
@Test()
public void myTest2() {
    List<String> list = mock(List.class);

    when(list.contains(any(String.class))).thenReturn(false);
    when(list.contains("A")).thenReturn(true);

    when(list.get(any(Integer.class))).then(new Answer(){
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            throw new MyException((int)invocation.getArguments()[0]);
        }
    });
    when(list.get(0)).thenReturn("A");
}

class MyException extends RuntimeException{
    public MyException(int i){
        super(i + " is outside array bounds");
    }
}
```

I have worked around this issue by putting all the logic in the when().then() statement, but wondering if this is expected behavior?

My dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit:

This behavior is explained by @second link in the comments.

[How does Mockito handle overlapping matchers with multiple arguments in the thenReturn block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246106/how-does-mockito-handle-overlapping-matchers-with-multiple-arguments-in-the-then)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246106/how-does-mockito-handle-overlapping-matchers-with-multiple-arguments-in-the-then/40247083